# SQL round not workinnng

Tags: sql

I wondering if I am doing something round, here is my code:

```
SELECT 
ROUND(value, 4)
FROM Table1
```

The original value on table is 305847992.53 and even though I used round i stills teh same.
The desirable value is 305847993.00

Comment: Which database system are you using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second argument of the `ROUND()` function is the number of decimals to include. Your code includes 4 decimals. You are saying you don't want any decimals, so just use `0` as the second argument.

Reproducible example in MySQL

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Table1 ` (
  `value` DOUBLE unsigned NOT NULL
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `Table1 ` (`value`) VALUES
 (305847992.53);
```

rounding:

```
SELECT 
ROUND(value, 0)
FROM Table1
```

results:

```
305847993
```